# How to configure mutiple struts-config.xml by module wise for single project?

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have 3 modules namely Supervisor,Sysadmin,users. I want to configure separate struts-config.xml for module wise. The strut-config will be placed inside WEB-INF/Supervisor same like others. Jsp pages also placed accordingly. my question is **How to forward from one module page to an other module page by action?** sorry for bad english.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solved your problem, else provide the update on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this URL will help you to elaborate your understanding about Struts Configuration.
**[Struts Multiple Module Configuration.](http://pentagon/downloads/java/struts/docs/userGuide/configuration.html#dd_config_modules)**